# signed fractional multiplication using q(4,20)

Tags: python, signal-processing, signed, fractions

I am doing a simple test to understand signed fractional multiplication in ordinary format
and in Q(4,20) format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)). I am using the fxpmath library (https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath) to achieve the Q(4,20) conversion.

I have an issue when testing my case 2, details below.

*my code*

```
from fxpmath import Fxp

# data set
data= [-0.003, 1.0, 0.707, -0.707, -0.002121, 0.002121]

print("---------------------------------------------")
print("signed_fractional_value""\t¦", "Q(4,20) value")
print("---------------------------------------------")

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    # convert to Q(4,20) format
    x = Fxp(data[i], signed=True, n_word=24, n_frac=20)   
    print("%.6f" % data[i],"\t\t¦", x.hex())
```

*output*

```
---------------------------------------------
signed_fractional_value ¦ Q(4,20) value
---------------------------------------------
-0.003000               ¦ 0xFFF3B7
1.000000                ¦ 0x100000
0.707000                ¦ 0x0B4FDF
-0.707000               ¦ 0xF4B021
-0.002121               ¦ 0xFFF750
0.002121                ¦ 0x0008B0
```

### case 1 : -0.003 * 1.0 = -0.003

Now I try the multiplication in Q(4,20) domain for the above numbers by looking at corresponding value in above table and I expect the result to be 0xFFF3B7

```
>>> hex(0xFFF3B7 *  0x100000)
'0xfff3b700000'
>>> hex((0xFFF3B7 *  0x100000) >> 20)
'0xfff3b7'
```

### case 2 : -0.003 * 0.707 = -0.002121

Now doing the same for the second case,
I am expecting to get 0xFFF750 as shown in the table

```
>>> hex(0xFFF3B7 *  0x0B4FDF)
'0xb4f5407c569'
>>> hex((0xFFF3B7 *  0x0B4FDF) >> 20)
'0xb4f540'
```

I am expecting the value to be 0xFFF750 but what I receive is 0xb4f540, I am sure there is something wrong.

Could someone explain what am I missing here.

Comment: Signed values need to be shifted in a special way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

You have problem with resolution, `Q4.20` is not enough to represent exact floating-point values.

## Long answer

Let's convert the FP numbers into Fxp numbers:

```py
data_fxp = Fxp(data, dtype='Q4.20')
data_fxp
```

> fxp-s24/20([-0.00299931  1.          0.70699978 -0.70699978 -0.00212097  0.00212097])

If you have a large `data` array, the easy way to check if some values are inaccurate, do:

```py
data_fxp.status['inaccuracy']
```

> True

Let's check the *hex* values:

```py
data_fxp.hex()
```

> ['0xFFF3B7', '0x100000', '0x0B4FDF', '0xF4B021', '0xFFF750', '0x0008B0']

Then, when you are using *hex* value `0xFFF3B7` you are not using `-0.003` but `-0.00299931`. When you multiply this number with `1.0` there are not problems, but when you multiply it with `0x0B4FDF` (originally `0.707`), you are multiplying for `0.70699978`.

But the problem does not end here. To keep enough precision to store the result of a multiplication, the resulting fxp shall have the sum of the word sizes. Let's check:

```py
data_fxp[0] * data_fxp[2]     # 0xFFF3B7 * 0x0B4FDF
```

> fxp-s48/40(-0.0021205084840403288)

Check that you need 48 bits for whole binary and 40 bits for fractional part. But if you wanna keep the same size:

```py
(data_fxp[0] * data_fxp[2]).like(Fxp(dtype='Q4.20'))
```

> fxp-s24/20(-0.0021200180053710938)

and the hex value (and other way to resize):

```py
x = data_fxp[0] * data_fxp[2]
x.resize(dtype='Q4.20')
x.hex()
```

> '0xFFF751'

You can see that the result is closer what you are looking for, but it's not the same because not enough precision and carrying errors (also because approximations).

If you always want to work with same size `Q4.20` you can use a template, for example:

```py
Fxp.template = Fxp(dtype='Q4.20', op_sizing='same')

data_fxp = Fxp(data)

# calculate all cross-products using matrix multiplication
np.array(np.multiply(data_fxp[:,np.newaxis], data_fxp[np.newaxis, :]).like(data_fxp).hex()).tolist()
```

[image]